# javascript's function not working second time

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I am using the below `function of javascript` to enable and disable the `radio buttons` and `textbox` as the value of `drop down` changes.
 it is fine in starting but as I click on the submit button and if `myindex = 8 or 9` at the time of submit it does not work.
At this time `radio button filter[0] and filter[1]` should be disable and `textfield count` should be enable I called this function in while selecting dropdown and while clicking on submit button.
 I dont know why it is not working. Any Help.

```
function OnChange(dropdown) {
    var myindex = dropdown.selectedIndex;

    document.form.filter[0].disabled = false;
    document.form.filter[1].disabled = false;

    if (myindex == 8) {
        document.form.filter[0].disabled = true;
        document.form.filter[1].disabled = true;
        document.form.count.disabled = false;
        document.form.submit.disabled = false;
    } else if (myindex == 9) {
        alert("in ALL");
        document.form.filter[0].disabled = true;
        document.form.filter[1].disabled = true;
        document.form.count.disabled = true;
        document.form.submit.disabled = false;

        alert(document.form.filter[0].disabled);
    }

    else {
        document.form.filter[0].disabled = false;
        document.form.filter[1].disabled = false;
        document.form.count.disabled = true;
        document.form.submit.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML code below.

```
<s:form action="crInquiry" name="form" >
    <table align="center" width="1020">
        <tr>
            <td>Batch Id : <s:property value="batchId" />
                <fieldset
                    style="background-color: #F7F9F3; margin: 2px; padding: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 5pt; border: 1px solid #A7CBE3;">
                    <legend class="field_label">
                        <strong>Inquiry Log Status</strong>
                    </legend>
                    <table border="0" id="main_table1" cellpadding="5" width="1010"
                        cellspacing="5" align="center">
                        <tr style="height: 5px;">
                            <td width="300" height="2" align="left" colspan="0"><s:hidden
                                    name="batchId" id="batchId"
                                    onfocus="OnChange((this.form.filterValue));"
                                    value="%{ batchId }"></s:hidden> <s:select
                                    cssClass="bulkSelect" name="filterValue"
                                    label="Search Criteria" required="true" theme="css_xhtml"
                                    labelposition="bottom" tabindex="2" list="headerList"
                                    onchange="OnChange(this.form.filterValue);" />
                            </td>


                            <td width="180"><s:radio name="filter"
                                    requiredposition="right"
                                    list="#{'STATUS_FILTER_START':'START','STATUS_FILTER_END':'END'}"
                                    label="Stage" labelposition="right" theme="css_xhtml"
                                    tabindex="9" labelposition="bottom"></s:radio>
                            </td>
                            <td width="50" height="2"><s:textfield disabled="true"
                                    value="0" name="count" size="2" labelposition="1"
                                    theme="css_xhtml"></s:textfield>
                            </td>
                            <td width="180"><s:radio name="order"
                                    requiredposition="right" list="#{'ASC':'ASC','DESC':'DESC'}"
                                    label="Order" labelposition="right" theme="css_xhtml"
                                    tabindex="9" labelposition="bottom"></s:radio>
                            </td>
                            </td>


                            <td width="50"><s:submit theme="css_xhtml" value="Filter"
                                    align="left" onclick="gotopage('FilteredInquiryLog');"></s:submit>
                            </td>
                            <td width="59"><s:submit theme="css_xhtml" value="Details"
                                    onclick="gotopage('crInquiry')"></s:submit></td>

                        </tr>


                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</s:form>
```

and from submit I call the js function from where it call the above js function

```
function gotopage(actionname) { 
        document.form.action = actionname + ".action";
        document.form.submit();
        OnChange(document.form.filterValue);

    }
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and show the code that calls this function from the submit operation.

Comment: @Nivesh: how can you possibly think that this is enough information for someone to be able to help you?

Comment: @bernie Please excuse, I have just added related code

Comment: you should really try to reduce the amount of code to reproduce the issue. its very difficult to understand what you are trying to do in a few minutes when you have so much stuff going on.

Comment: @DmitryB I think you are right I will reduce the code and will post it as a new question.

Comment: @NIVESHSENGAR Don't post it as a new question, fix this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems odd that you would submit the form and then try to manipulate the fields...

```
function gotopage(actionname) { 
        document.form.action = actionname + ".action";
        document.form.submit();
        OnChange(document.form.filterValue);

    }
```

perhaps what you need is :

```
function gotopage(actionname) { 
        OnChange(document.form.filterValue);

        document.form.action = actionname + ".action";
        document.form.submit();
    }
```